# union of $[-r,r] ,r\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have some basis questions:

I know if  $r \in \mathbb{R}$,We cay say $\cup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}(-r,r)=(-\infty,\infty)$.

Even if $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}}(-r,r)=(-\infty,\infty)$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

But What is $\cup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}[-r,r]$?

I know $(-r,r) \subsetneq [-r,r] \implies\cup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}(-r,r) \subsetneq \cup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}[-r,r]\implies (-\infty,\infty)\subsetneq \cup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}[-r,r]$ where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have $A_n$ and $B_n$ are subets of $X$ and $A_n$ is strictly included in $B_n$ and $\cup_n A_n=\cup_nB_n$. You just point a particular example of that situation.